# Can you use Node Inspector with the .coffee handler?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, node-debugger

Debugging node apps using [node-inspector](http://npmjs.org/package/node-inspector) is pretty simple if you're scripting using JavaScript or compiled Coffee (`coffee -c -m script.coffee`).

However, when using the coffeescript `require` handler:

```
 require('coffee-script/register');
 require('lib/component.coffee');
```

in a script I'm trying to debug using `node-debug`, I get:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { #
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
  at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  ...
```

right as I `require` the file.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I have several CoffeeScript files that I would much rather *not* have to compile each time I want to test.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, definitely. I use it all the time, the command line looks like these:

```
node-inspector & coffee  --nodejs --debug-brk ./scripts/mongoEtl.coffee

node-inspector & mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script ./test/dataLayer-test.coffee --ui bdd --debug-brk

node-inspector --web-port=5870 & mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register ./test/dataLayer-test.coffee --ui bdd --debug-brk=5880 -g 'my test name here'
```

I just checked the last line, it's working and has coffeescript requires in it. However when I'm debugging I'm actually seeing javascript, not coffee. I don't know if it's possible to run and debug coffeescript with node-inspector (edit: yes, it is, use of source maps is required but that is out of scope for this answer). I'm not convinced that has value -- I think it's good to be able to read javascript well, so I haven't looked into it.

I think your issue might be in the compilation, have you tried compiling the file that's being required?

Comment: I don't get why you're using mocha in this case? I want to debug my production project, not my test case :)